# How Should the First Sessions of an Undergrad. Course Be?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

Form a teaching perspective, the first sessions of an undergraduate mathematics course are of a great importance. They can make clear the aims of the course, and point out to the main problems and typical examples of the mathematical objects which the course is about, and so on.

I need an article, website or book about how should the first sessions be designed and what are its main components. Your opinions are also welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you were more specific, your question is over-broad and any answer is likely just to be an opinion.

Comment: @ErikG Well, I'm looking for general guidelines not specific one!

Comment: A teacher should have the knowledge in his spinal cord.  From here  he knows to design any lessons of a course.  If you are new to teaching, ask some very experienced collogues to visit their lessons and take the best from their approaches.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single answer to your question, but here are some guidelines for the first class.

Put yourself in the students' shoes: what do they want to know? In no particular order, we might have

- Who are you and how can I get in touch with you? If you are using Teaching Assistants, who are they and how can I get in touch with them?
- What are the mechanics of the course? How many homework assignments/exams/other tasks will there be? When will they be due?
- How will my grade be calculated?
- What materials will be used? For instance, is there a text, are there any supplemental readings?
- Briefly, what is the subject matter of the course? What are the topics to be covered and what is the schedule of coverage?

In the first few minutes of the first session, I cover these questions *very* briefly and refer my students to the syllabus, which I have handed out and which is also available online. I rarely spend more than five minutes on these introductory questions, trusting that my students can read the syllabus (though, frankly, few do, but it at least gives me a chance to answer the questions three weeks later by saying "Check the syllabus; you'll find the date of Exam 1 there.")

This introduction will vary from class to class, depending on the class. I spent a bit more time on the introduction in my introductory class and less time in a class populated by third- and fourth-year majors, all of whom had taken one or more classes from me.

Having done that, I still have most of the session to dive into the material, which I do.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for expansion.